# file --mime doc.html return : doc.html: text/x-c++; charset=utf-8 on debian

Tags: php, html, file-upload, debian, mime

have problem on use php mimetype detection. think that is related to debian config files
command :

```
file --mime doc.html
```

return : doc.html: text/x-c++; charset=utf-8

doc.html file: http://dpaste.com/hold/1709425/
also tried this

```
<?php echo mime_content_type('doc.html') ;?>
```

that return: text/x-c++
but when use this command :

```
mimetype doc.html
```

return text/html. this problem cause on using ojs when upload html files detect it as text/x-c++ and name it as untitled instead of html
i read all ojs FAQ about this problem and try them with no success
http://pkp.sfu.ca/wiki/index.php/PKP_Frequently_Asked_Questions#HTML_Galleys_don.27t_display_properly_.2F_files_I_upload_aren.27t_being_identified_properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, that related to special character inside html codes.
when i use this site:
http://infohound.net/tidy/
to make html code clean, OJS detect html code and command:
    file --mime doc.html
detect file and html